# Number of integer solutions of the inequality $x^2+y^2\leqslant n$

Tags: number-theory

Let $N$ be the number of integer solutions $(x,y)$ of $x^2+y^2\leqslant n$. In page 45 of **The Method of Coordinates** (By I. M. Gelfand, E. G. Glagoleva, A. A. Kirillov), it is shown that
$$
|N-\pi n|\leqslant 2\pi(\sqrt{2n}+1)
$$
Is there a known better estimate for $N$ ?

Comment: in Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, by Richard K. Guy. Section F1, on page 240 in the second edition (1994). It seems they have been trying for an error estimate bounded by $\sqrt[4]n \; . \;  $   Hardy and Landau showed that was too optimistic; Iwaniec ans Mozzochi, 1988, showed $n^{7/22}$   Title On the Divisor and Circle problems, Journal of NUmber Theory, volume 29  pages60-93  SEE  https://conf.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/circledivisorsurvey.pdf  by Bruce Berndt

Comment: Thanks @Will Jagy